# How to alert an upcoming date in a column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I need to evaluate if there are 5 days remaining from the current date until the date entered in a cell, and if it's true paint the row in red and generate an alert message informing this situation.

For example:
Today is 25/05/2017

The column has the values:

01/06/2017
03/06/2017
29/06/2017

So the program must alert about the dates 01/06/2017 and 29/06/2017.
It's not necessary that the alert message contains every date, if there are 2 cells < 5 days remaining it generates 2 alert messages.

I will appreciate any help, I don't know how to program in VBA and it's a little complex for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the painting, the easiest way is to use Conditional Formatting. Add a new rule with the formula:

```
=AND(A1-Today()<5;A1>=Today())
```

Where your dates will be in column A.

An alert for every date that is less than 5 days from today can be accomplished with:

```
For Each cell In Range("A4:A6")
    If cell.Value - Now < 5 Then
        MsgBox "Row " & cell.Row & " has less than 5 days"
        ' optional alterative to conditional formatting for painting
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

To be pasted in `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

With ActiveCell
    If IsDate(.Value) Then
        If .Value - Now < 5 Then
            If .Value >= Now Then
                MsgBox ("Tic-Tac Tic-Tac... time come soon!")
                Range(.Row & ":" & .Row).Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```